# data won't be deleted in a uitableview after updating the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, persistent-storage

I have been reading so many topics here about this, but I could not have found it yet.

I want to have a UITableView where I can put some dictionaries and inside them, have words with some fields (about 4). So far it is ok, but my question is what is the best way to don't erase the data after upgrading the app to a new version. I mean, when an user upgrade the app, all those words/dictionaries won't be deleted because of the update.

I don't know if I should use a NSMutableArray of class of words (for example), or use Core Data, or SQLite.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does NSUserDefaults get erased when updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dictionaries that are in fact NSDictionaries, serializing them using NSCoding protocol to a file inside of the documents is easy, fast and reliable. The contents of the Documents directory remain unchanged if you do an upgrade of the app.

This is the code I use in one of my apps (it saves a list of quotes that has been favorited by the user)

```
- (BOOL) saveQuotesToDisk
{
    //get path to events list    
    NSArray * dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * fullpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0], @"FavQuoteList.plist"];

    //create data to be saved
    NSMutableDictionary * rootObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [rootObject setValue: _SavedQuotes forKey:@"_SavedQuotes"];

    //write data
    bool success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: rootObject
                                               toFile: fullpath];

    if (success) NSLog(@"Quotes list saved.");
    else NSLog(@"ERROR on saving quotes list!");

    return success;
}

- (BOOL) readFavoriteQuotesFromDisk
{
    //get path to quote list    
    NSArray * dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * fullpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0], @"FavQuoteList.plist"];

    //read data
    NSDictionary * rootObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: fullpath ];
    _SavedQuotes = [[rootObject valueForKey:@"_SavedQuotes"] retain];

    //check data
    if (_SavedQuotes == nil) return NO;
    else return YES;
}
```

You can add more objects to the `rootObject` as long as they conform to NSCoding Protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess _SavedQuotes is an NSMutableArray, right? Could i add more objects to rootObject called for exmaple "_Words" with a new key right? I would like to have after all those words a search option where I could find everything i want in those dictionaries.

Comment: Yes _SavedQuotes is an NSMutableArray of objects of type Quote. You may keep adding more objects to the rootObject - anything that complies with NSCoding, so arrays, dictionaries, sets, whatever you like.

Comment: Hi again and thanks! NSMutableArray doesn't compile with NSCoding, just NSArray. What should I do? Maybe I am doing something wrong and that is what it gives me an error

Comment: nevermind. It was another mistake. It works very well now!! Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can store that data in NSUserDefaults or in Documents directory.. Documents directory's content don't get deleted when you update..

Comment: Thanks!! I will try this too. I am not used to code with NSUserDefaults, but I will try it

Comment: if you think any of the answer helped you then please upvote and accept that answer..